# Entity Framework Navigation Properties not loading til new DbContext is established

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm still relatively new to EF, so forgive me if I'm missing an obvious concept.

Let me see if I can simplify this...Old question is in edit history, but I think I can distill this down:

FWIW, `DbContext` is *PER REQUEST*, not `static`, which is why the first example works. *Not* using DI/IoC on the controller at this point.

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController {
    private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

    //controller methods....

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
      db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Works** (2 separate requests):

```
//request 1: client code sends in a new order to be added to db
public Order Post([FromBody]Order order) {
  db.Orders.Add(order);
  db.SaveChanges();

  return order;
}

//request 2: someone punches a button to send an email to CS about this order
public void NotifyCustomerService(int orderid) {
  var order = db.Orders.Find(orderid);
  //do email code here
}
```

**Broken** (single request):

```
//request: client code sends in a new order to be added to db AND notifies CS at same time
public Order Post([FromBody]Order order) {
  db.Orders.Add(order);
  db.SaveChanges();

  //notify CS via email here (nav properties are not populating)

  return order;
}
```

**Works** (single request) (but i know this is horrible practice):

```
//request: client code sends in a new order to be added to db AND notifies CS at same time (using a new dbcontext in the notification code)
public Order Post([FromBody]Order order) {
  db.Orders.Add(order);
  db.SaveChanges();

  using(var db2 = new MyDbContext()) {
    var sameOrderWTF = db.Orders.Find(order.ID);
    //notify CS via email using sameOrderWTF instance here (nav properties ARE populating)
  }
  return order;
}
```

So, it seems to me, that there's some side effect of adding a new never-before-seen entity to the context, and then trying to get it's nav properties to populate. But if you create a new DbContext... even in the same request, it has to directly hit the DB for that entity, not use the in-mem copy, so then the nav properties magically work. That's the part that has me stumped.

**Working Solution**

```
//request: client code sends in a new order to be added to db AND notifies CS at same time
public Order Post([FromBody]Order o) {
  Order order = db.Orders.Create();
  db.Orders.Add(order);

  //copy values from input to proxy instance
  db.Entry(order).CurrentValues.SetValues(o);

  //copy input lines to proxy instance (same process as order for each line)
  o.OrderLines.ToList().ForEach(l => {
    var line = db.OrderLines.Create();
    db.OrderLines.Add(line);
    db.Entry(line).CurrentValues.SetValues(l);
    order.OrderLines.Add(line);
  });

  db.SaveChanges();

  //notify CS via email here (nav properties are not populating)

  return order;
}
```

So while we'll consider this question answered (thanks Uber Bot), the need to go through all of that seems more laborious than my other (admittedly short) experience with ASP.NET MVC and EF. I guess maybe I should be using ViewModels and mapping the VM properties to a proxy instance instead of trying to use the EF classes directly, but I just can't really see the benefit for a simple call like this.

Comment: Did you mark those Navigation Properties with the `virtual` keyword?

Comment: Also, there's no reason to explicitly change the state of each `line` to `Added`. It's already in that state.

Comment: Also, why query the database when you already have the generated `Order` in memory? Use its data for emailing.

Comment: @haim770: 1) Yes, they are marked virtual. I did not change the classes that EF generated. Will update question to show example. 2) Are you saying I only need to do `db.Entry(order)` to add it to the context? 3) I'm not. in the first example, the `post` and `notify` methods were being called on separate requests, so the order would need to be retrieved in that case. My 'new version' is specifically trying to use the copy in memory, which is where my issue is coming from... not loading the nav properties on the "in memory" copy.

Comment: Ok i was going to write an answer but at this point the code still doesn't make sense. Ill explain... you are not modifying the entities.. other than changing their state... so what i suggest is... that you show the code where they were modified as well. as others have stated... depending on how they were retrieve and if your still in the same context, then the context knows everything it needs to and you can just call savechanges()

Comment: @Seabizkit: I added the client side code that's calling the controller methods, hopefully that helps. They were never 'retrieved' from anywhere the dbcontext knows about, so I'm assuming that's why the nav properties won't populate, but how to make that happen within the same DbContext is beyond me

Comment: Is `db` a static reference on your Controller? Also, if you do not call `Get` before calling `Post`, there will not be an `db.Entry` for you to work on. I suggest you move your db construnction inside each method and in the post case, just call `db.Order.Insert` or load it by Id, update the values and save.

Comment: OK, did some frantic searching as `db.Entry(order)` didn't work. Looks like the 'right' way to add new entities is `db.Orders.Add(order)`. That works and is definitely much cleaner. Updated question. Still have the issue of nav properties not populating within the same context tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new Order entity instance is not wrapped by proxy and so lazy loading will not work.

You can force context to load navigational property.

```
db.Entry(order).Reference(o => o.YouProperty).Load();
```

Or you can create an instance by using context's factory to overcome this problem.

```
db.Orders.Create();
```

> A proxy instance will not be created if you create an instance of an
>   entity using the new operator. This may not be a problem, but if you
>   need to create a proxy instance (for example, so that lazy loading or
>   proxy change tracking will work) then you can do so using the Create
>   method of DbSet.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much. That's exactly what I'm running into. Let me implement, see what happens and I'll get back with results.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Updating end of question with my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI... could be simplified like..... you should add validation.

```
//only handles new orders...as is
//Assumes!!! Order is of a type which is a db Entity! (Table)
//Assumes that you populated "order" with all the required properties.

public Order Post([FromBody]Order order) 
{
    db.Orders.Add(order);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return order;
}
```

Checking your code.... again it seems like "Order" **in the Method signature** is not a db Order entity, not sure tho if it isn't you should rename it so that it's not confusing. I.e. rename it as OrderDTO or something else which is not the same name as the db Order. It will make understanding of your code much clearer.

Comment: As Uber Bot explained, it isn't. It's an instance of the EF-generated POCO class, but it's _not_ wrapped by the dynamically generated proxy that handles lazy loading, etc. That was the core of my issue. Interestingly, things like computed properties worked just fine (e.g. Database Generated ID for the order), it was only lazy loading that seemed to be problematic. Makes me wonder if there's a way to proxy a non-wrapped instance... e.g. `db.Orders.WrapWithProxy(order)` or `db.Orders.Create(order)` .... would prevent the need to map from a DTO to an Entity

Comment: @BLSully mind blow...;-) thx, i would need to google more... I know you are saying lots but its not sinking in. Not sure how this is related to what i was saying... I'm in no means saying your wrong/right... I'm just not following, which is no fault of yours... what is the key difference here... so I may google that more. regardless of how the EF models are generated code first vs db generated... navigation would still work. But not sure how that relates to naming of Entities as well. I feel i may learn something here please point me to something to read. thx

Comment: I sorta went off on a tangent, but I was addressing your statement that **Order in the method sig is not a EF Entity**. It _is_, at least as far as it is an instance of the EF-generated POCO class, but it is _not_ a full "Entity" (for lack of a better word) because it does not have the wrapper proxy. The `Order` as it exists in the controller method is generated by deserialization of a JSON body, so Json.NET is calling `new Order()` and populating the properties. In theory, if Json.NET could detect an EF POCO and it could instantiate via `db.Orders.Create()`, then we'd all be in good shape ;)

Comment: Thanks that was easier reading. If the "Order" class in the method sig is a POCO class, then my example stands and should work(done the same and way more complicated myself). The reason I suspect that it is not a PODO calss...is because it has "Lines" vs "OrderLines" see original question -> working solution.

Comment: Ah, that was just my fault for editing badly. My real class names have domain specific info in them I'd rather not have on a public site, so I renamed (badly) some things for the purposes of the question. ;)

Comment: @BLSully cool cool, was just saying if you update it with the correct names, its easier to understand... and then someone could suggest tools like AutoMapper to assist here, this is normally how you transform from DTO class to POCO Class, which then would allow you to simply do. content.Orders.Add(order); content.SaveChanges(); Anyways i'm glad we cleared that up ;-) all the best.